# How to delete the build pipelines and release pipelines?

Tags: azure, azure-pipelines

Unable to delete the release pipeline:

[image]

Unable to delete the build pipeline also:

[image]

I have all permissions to make changes to the pipeline from creation to modification, deletion. Still, I'm getting these errors.

How to solve this issue?

Answer (score 3):

[image]

**This is because of  retention lease, So Click on remove all button, then you can see delete button as per the step-3.
Please follow the steps mentioned in the screenshot.**